# "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" when deleting array

Tags: c++, free

I'm writing a 2D game engine in C++/SFML, and I ran into a problem I can't figure out:

So, I have this class here:

```
class StringInfo : public Object
{
    public:
        inline StringInfo(void) { m_data = NULL; m_string = ""; m_bitmapFont = NULL; invalidate(); }
        ~StringInfo(void);
        void create(String _string, BitmapFont& font, Color color);
        inline TexInfo* getData(void) { return m_data; }
        inline uint32 length(void) { return m_string.length(); }
        inline String getString(void) { return m_string; }
        inline char at(uint32 index) { return m_string[index]; }

    private:
        TexInfo* m_data;
        String m_string;
        BitmapFont* m_bitmapFont;
};
```

and this is the implementation:

```
StringInfo::~StringInfo(void)
{
    if (m_data != NULL)
    {
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = NULL;
    }
    m_bitmapFont = NULL;
}

void StringInfo::create(String _string, BitmapFont& font, Color color)
{
    if (_string.trim() == "")
    {
        GameData::instance().errorQueue.push(Error::EMPTY_STRING, ERROR_DATA());
        return;
    }
    m_string = _string;
    m_bitmapFont = &font;

    m_string = String(" ").add(m_string);
    m_data = new TexInfo[m_string.length()];
    for (uint32 i = 0; i < m_string.length(); i++)
        m_data[i] = font.getChar(m_string.at(i), color);

    setValid(true);
}
```

This is working fine on Windows/MinGW, but on Linux I get the error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" on this line:

```
delete[] m_data;
```

I can't figure out why, what is wrong with the way I'm doing this?

Just in case, here is the TexInfo structure

```
struct TexInfo
{
    FPoint texCoords;
    FPoint texSize;
    Color tintColor;

    TexInfo(FPoint coords = FPoint(-1, -1), FPoint size = FPoint(0, 0), Color tint = Color::White)
    {
        texCoords = coords;
        texSize = size;
        tintColor = tint;
    }
};
```

nothing is beeing allocated dynamically here, both FPoint and Color have just some floats and integers in them.

Comment: Tip: In C++ try and use `nullptr` instead of C's `NULL`. You can also omit `(void)` in function signatures. `()` is fine. Additionally the `inline` declarations here are superfluous, as you actually define them inline so that's understood.

Comment: Don't forget to pass in arguments as `const` references whenever possible to avoid excessive copying and accidental mutations. You'll also want to learn about [Constructor Lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) which can simplify and clean up constructors considerably. There's also no need to explicitly `NULL` out properties in a destructor. That doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Do you delete[] m_data anywhere other than the destructor? Also, you shouldn't be using owning raw pointers that you delete in destructors! Use shared_ptr or unique_ptr instead, or vectors. It would prevent problems like this.

Comment: I'm confused by the `create()` function. That looks like a constructor, but you call it separately? I'd expect to see two constructors, one `()`, the other with those arguments. You may also want to switch to `std::vector<TexInfo> m_data` to offload memory management responsibility.

Comment: If that `StringInfo` is being copied around, passed or returned by value, etc. after `create` is called, that is an instant double-free.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: *This is working fine on Windows/MinGW,* -- And once you fix the issue running under Linux, go back and fix the Windows version.  It is also broken, even though you say it's "working fine".

Comment: @Anonymous1847 no, I don't delete it anywhere else. Also, I can't really get my head around smart pointers yet.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I will try with a vector, that should fix it...but I'm still curious as to why I get the error

Comment: It's likely as Paul points out: If this structure gets inadvertently copied then because you don't have a copy constructor it uses the default and just *literally copies the pointer* from one instance to the clone. As such two objects end up with the same pointer, and after the first is destroyed, the second will have a stale pointer, so kaboom.

Comment: If you use `std::vector<...>` then it's automatically safe to copy, it's not your problem. This fixes a *lot* of RIAA issues. If you don't know what RIAA is, as Ted points out, time to learn.

Comment: @Sylar But see, that's the beauty of smart pointers. You don't need to get your head around them. You just use them. Just everything you delete, (but not delete[]), make its declaration `std::shared_ptr<T>` and remove the deletes everywhere. Things you delete[] can be replaced with `std::vector` (also removing all the delete[]s.) Manual memory management is what takes getting your head around something.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah sorry, I meant that I'm just not getting the error on Windows. Also, could you argument a bit more on your first comment? for learning purposes, at this point

Comment: @Sylar You didn't define a copy constructor. (Another thing which would not be a problem with the right smart pointers!) Therefore, when you copy a `StringInfo`, the pointers inside are copied, but not the things they point to. Then, when both of them are destroyed, they both try to delete[] the same pointers. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: I think I'll undelete the answer and take the hits in hope that it helps OP more.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 That makes sense, I get it now...just for learning sake, the right thing would be to define a copy-constructor in which I should copy the data inside of m_data array manually?

Comment: @Sylar The study of 3/5/0 springs to mind.

Comment: @Sylar For learning's sake, sure, you could do that. But in production try to use smart pointers and vectors. ;)

Comment: @Sylar The other issue is that your `StringInfo` class is holding onto a `BitmapFont` address that it doesn't manage the lifetime of.  If that `BitmapFont` that is passed into `create` goes out of scope, that is now a dangling pointer.  You really should be using something like `std::shared_ptr<BitmapFont>` if indeed you don't know who will manage the pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You could write an answer with your insights if you'd like. Also, I would advise considering ownership still before you default for shared_ptr due to not knowing what belongs to what, because you could end up with cycles of ownership and create subtle memory leaks that way. Try to keep ownership well-defined and hierarchical.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 "_I would advise considering ownership still before you default for `shared_ptr`_" sounds like something I'd upvote given what I know you'll provide. My answer is lacking a bit in that department.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't figure out why, what is wrong with the way I'm doing this?

This may be hard to read - but this design will not survive

```
TexInfo* m_data;
BitmapFont* m_bitmapFont;
```

unless you take extreme measures.

You *must* study RAII and, with that, the rule of [3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to not dig a grave all to deep.

Comment: Raw pointers by themselves aren't an immediate problem. Owning raw pointers may be. So m_bitmapFont is probably fine but m_data isn't, as we've seen.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 "_Raw pointers by themselves aren't an immediate problem_" - they are a sign of something you need to consider. With that - you, as a programmer, caused an indirect problem.

Comment: I'll look into RAII and also the rule of 3/5/0 ...I'm guessing I've still got some way ahead in fully understanding memory management in C++

Comment: @Sylar Yes, but it becomes rather nice when you've done it once. Don't keep two pointers in the same class. They each need their own RAII class.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But not always. If they are not owning pointers that you don't have to delete, raw pointers is fine. Say in a Node class for a tree, where destroying a node destroys its subtree, a raw pointer to parent is ok, because parent will always outlive the child.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Agreed - but that scenario is almost always academic.